# Xpath for importxml in Google Sheets

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to extract https://www.adobe.com from the first paragraph here https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/adobe/

Can someone help me with the xpath?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Be more specific. What is the question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the URL redirets to a page that doesn't include the text to be scraped.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/adobe/","//*[@adhocenable='false'][@target='_blank']/@href")
```

It will give you all the links in that content.

And to get only the first one just add + at the beginning of the formula, that is, try the following formula:

```
=+IMPORTXML("https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/adobe/","//*[@adhocenable='false'][@target='_blank']/@href")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be as dynamic as possible and apply to any of the case studies ( all of which can be found on this page here: https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/all/ ) you can use this xpath:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(B2,"//p/a[@target='_blank']/@href"),2,)
```

There are one or two cases where they may not have a URL listed at all for company in the case study, so by default import xml would return #N/A, but to return a clean result regardless of whether or not it is there, you can wrap your functions in `IFERROR`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(IMPORTXML(B2,"//p/a[@target='_blank']/@href"),2,))
```

[image]